# How does $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}$ become $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-kx}$?

Tags: summation, exponential-sum

How does $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}$ become $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-kx}$?

I know $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}-1\right)^{-1}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^{-1}$ and we know $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x$

Comment: $q = e^{-x}$. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^k = \frac{q}{1-q}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall the geometric series ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)): for any $y$ with $|y|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty y^k.$$
Therefore, for any such $y$, we also have
$$\frac{y}{1-y}=y+y^2+y^3+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty y^k.$$
Now let $y=e^{-x}$ (though observe that we need $x>0$ to have $e^{-x}<1$).

Answer (score 2):

You have if $|a|<1$:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a^i = \frac{1}{1-a}
$$
therefore:
$$
\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}= e^{-x}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left({e^{-x}}\right)^i = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What is the series for $$\frac{1}{ x - 1}$$?